# SELECT with multiple PRIMARY KEY

Tags: sql, postgresql, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I have 3 table:

```
nation (name PRIMARY KEY);
city (name PRIMARY KEY, nation REFERENCES nation(name))
overflight (number, city, PRIMARY KEY (number, city))
```

The overflight table content is something like below:

```
AA11 city1

AA11 city2

BB22 city1

BB22 city3
```

etc.

I need to select only overflight that doesn't have city from a certain nation in the city field.

I've tried with:

```
SELECT number 
FROM overflight 
JOIN city ON overflight.city = city.name 
WHERE overflight.city NOT IN (
  SELECT name FROM city WHERE nation = some_nation
) 
GROUP BY number;
```

but it doesn't work because it doesn't list the row of overflight that have city from some_nation but can happen that the same overflight have another row in the table that doesn't have city in some_nation. How can I display only the overflight that doesn't have city in some_nation at all?

Hope that I've explained my problem as clear as possible.

**EDIT**
This is exact content of overflight table:

```
AZ 7255 Rome
AZ 7255 Milan
AZ 608 Rome
AZ 608 New York
AA 1 New York
AA 1 Los Angeles
BA 2430 New York
BA 2430 Los Angeles
```

Suppose that I want to show the overflight that doesn't fly over any city in Italy. I need that the result is like this

```
AA 1 New York
AA 1 Los Angeles
BB 2430 New York
BB 2430 Los Angeles
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the tables to get the overflight numbers that do have a city from the nation that you want to exclude and use the operator `NOT IN` to select all the other oveflights:

```
SELECT * FROM overflight 
WHERE number NOT IN (
  SELECT o.number
  FROM overflight o INNER JOIN city c
  ON o.city = c.name
  WHERE c.nation = 'Italy'
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b7c6e2de535d52530b7c9767ff868c52).
Results:

| number | city |
| --- | --- |
| AA 1 | New York |
| AA 1 | Los Angeles |
| BA 2430 | New York |
| BA 2430 | Los Angeles |

Comment: I've tried this solution but it returns like below:
`AZ 608 New York
AA 1 New York
AA 1 Los Angeles
BA 2430 New York
BA 2430 Los Angeles`
This solution doesn't show only the row where the city in not in that nation but I have the same number on multiple row so if with that number exist a fly over a city in that nation, every row with that number must not be showed

Comment: thanks for the answer! You help me a lot!